# Apache Flink RocksDB state management

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm reading 2 kafka topics in the same flink jobs.

- `Stream1`: Messages comes from the first topic are saved to rocksdb, then it will union with stream2.
- `Stream2`: Messages comes from the second topic are enriched with state saved by stream1, then it will union with the stream1.

Topic1 and topic 2 are different sources but basically the output is the same for two sources. I have to just enrich data come from topic2 with the data come from topic1.

Here is flow;

```
val stream1 = readKafkaTopic1().keyBy(_.memberId).map(saveMemberDetailsToRocksDB)
val stream2 = readKafkaTopic2().keyBy(_.memberId).map(readMemberDetailsAndEnrich)
stream1.union(stream2).addSink(kafkaProducer)
```

Here is the questions;

1. Is that flow good?
2. Can `stream2` access the state that saved by `stream1` for the same `memberId`?

Comment: Do You mean that You manually use RocksDB or just Flink state that is backed by RocksDb ?

Comment: Flink state that is backed by RocksDb, not manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that You should be able to achieve exactly what You want by using `KeyedCoProcessFunction`. This would like that more or less:

```
stream1
.keyBy(_.memberId)
.connect(stream2.keyBy(_.memberId))
.process(new CustomKeyedCoProcessFunction())
```

This way You could keep the state in single `KeyedCoProcessFunction`, so You could access that both for `stream1` and `stream2`.

So, for `processElement1` You could do the same thing You are doing inside `map` for  `stream1` and in `processElement2` You could to the same thing You are doing inside `map` for stream2.

Comment: Ohh that's cool. So, what about if i want to add new stream like stream2?  I guess i can connect 3 different streams?

Comment: You can't sadly. You will have to do it in two separate steps  so first connect `stream1` with `stream2` and then the result of that would have to be connected with `stream3`. If You have more streams to connect, then one trick You might try is to simply use `union`  all of them and then use `.keyBy(_.memberId) ` and finally call `process` on that. In this  case You will have to handle elements from all streams in single function so You will have to manually implement handling for elements of the specific stream.